# symfony/var-dumper in html format with live or hot reloading

Tags: symfony, debugging, symfony4, dump, var-dump

I use [symfony/var-dumper](https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper) with the `html` format, I am wondering if there is a way to watch this `html` file online, so as not to reload the page (live / hot reloading). Is there a ready-made solution in a Symfony? Do you think it makes sense to debug in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to write my own utility, it is easy to install and powerful. Everything is described in detail [in the github](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/symfony-var-dumper-browser).

You can check vidoe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OERq-XUUxZQ